# docker-desktop-data VM in WSL2

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can't access docker-desktop-data in WSL2 with command `wsl -d docker-desktop-data`. I suspect that docker desktop(with WSL) stores there docker volumes which I want to look at. Interestingly that for other VMs this method(`wsl -d <distroname>`) works. Why is it different for docker-desktop-data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for why we can't access it via `wsl -d docker-desktop-data`, that appears to be because it has a 0 byte `/init`.

As for how to inspect it, I used `wsl --export docker-desktop-data docker-desktop-data.tar` and just examined the resulting tar file.  I just recently installed Docker on Windows, so I haven't created any volumes yet to see if they are stored there.

*Updated:*

I don't believe this was possible at the time (but I'm not sure), but a better solution than exporting is:

```
$ findmnt -a | grep "version-pack-data\s"
| |-/mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/version-pack-data        /dev/sdf[/version-pack-data]          ext4          rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
# Using the block device returned (sdf in this case):
$ sudo mount /dev/sdf /mnt/wsl/instances/docker-desktop-data -o X-mount.mkdir
$ cd /mnt/wsl/instances/docker-desktop-data
```

This will allow you to view `docker-desktop-data` as its original Ext4 filesystem, with symlinks and permissions intact.

Comment: Note, if you (or I) were using the Insider build of Windows, I believe it now has the ability to mount vhdx files (or, if not now, then soon), so we could in theory just mount that to examine it.

Comment: Also thinking, if we wanted to get really hacky, we might could delete the WSL instance, modify the tar (perhaps with a minimal shell), and reimport it back in under the same name.

Comment: I guess this (0 byte `/init`) happened recently, because a few months ago, I remeber, that it was possible "to go into" that VM. After installation of Docker Desktop I played a bit with it and it was interesting for me why 2 additional wsl distros were created, so inspected both of them